# Using MgGraph PowerShell 1.0 - Update-MgGroup -AdditionalProperties how to update the resourceBehaviorOptions option?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, moodle, microsoft-graph-teams

The education institution, I am helping, uses the `Moodle Plugin Microsoft 0365 Integration` which I believe uses the latest `MgGraph v1.0` to create `Microsoft 365 Teams Groups`.

The `Moodle plugin` creates `Microsoft 365 Teams Groups` but some `Settings` can not be updated on the Admin Exchange Center after its creation, It returns an Error.

The property to be set being  [image: “Send copies of group conversations and events to group member”]

The error received is not really helping

[image]

This Microsoft 365 Teams Group uses the HiddenMembership Visibility since MS Teams Classes can also be used and for privacy reasons this visibility is used. Unfortunately, the PHP code created by the Moodle MS Plugin adds more security features that prevents the groups from sending emails to each other since the above property can not be updated.

To get more information about the error, I tried to use MgGraph to set the `Setting` programmatically

```
$params = @{
    AutoSubscribeNewMembers = $true
}
Update-MgGroup -GroupId $groupid -BodyParameter $params
```

Than I go the below error:

```
AutoSubscribeNewMembers parameter can't be true when SubscriptionEnabled 
is set to false on the  group.
```

Looking all around, I finally found where the `SubscriptionEnabled` value is set.

```
((get-MgGroup -GroupId $groupid).AdditionalProperties).resourceBehaviorOptions
```

> Outputs :

```
SubscriptionDisabled
SharePointMemberReadonly
CalendarMemberReadOnly
WelcomeEmailDisabled
SubscribeNewGroupMembers
HideGroupInOutlook
ConnectorsDisabled
AllowOnlyMembersToPost
```

I tried to remove that value from the Group's AdditionalProperties.resourceBehaviorOptions but get this error.

```
$resourceBehaviorOptionsParams = @{
    "SubscriptionDisabled" = "false";
}

$additionalParams = @{
   resourceBehaviorOptions = $resourceBehaviorOptionsParams 
}

Update-MgGroup -GroupId $groupid -AdditionalProperties $additionalParams
```

> Error

```
An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'resourceBehaviorOptions' when
     | reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartArray' node was expected.
```

How can I remove the `SubscriptionDisabled` Option from the `resourceBehaviorOptions` section ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got same error like below***

[image]

> The error usually occurs if you don't have proper license like
> **Exchange Online** or the subscription is **disabled** on that teams group.

When I ran the same **MgGraph commands** as you to know more about error, I got same response like below:

```
Connect-MgGraph
$groupid = "f2210ee6-451a-496b-8b39-c2xxxxxxxf"

$params = @{
    AutoSubscribeNewMembers = $true
}
Update-MgGroup -GroupId $groupid -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried the same script as you to remove the *SubscriptionDisabled* Option, I got **same error** like below:

```
$groupid = "f2210ee6-451a-496b-8b39-c289xxxxxdaf"
$resourceBehaviorOptionsParams = @{
    "SubscriptionDisabled" = "false";
}

$additionalParams = @{
   resourceBehaviorOptions = $resourceBehaviorOptionsParams 
}

Update-MgGroup -GroupId $groupid -AdditionalProperties $additionalParams
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you can **enable** subscription for that teams group using below Exchange Online commands:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Devi Team" -SubscriptionEnabled:$true
```

**Response:**

[image]

After enabling the subscription, I ran below command to **enable** `AutoSubscribeNewMembers` like this:

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Devi Team" -AutoSubscribeNewMembers:$true
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in **Exchange Admin Center**, option enabled successfully like below:

[image]

You can also enable ***"Allow external senders to email this group"*** option if needed from Portal like this after enabling subscription:

[image]

Comment: Hi Srinivas, thanks you nailed it! The 2 `Set-UnifiedGroup` group commands made the trick. On thing though the `((get-MgGroup -GroupId $groupid).AdditionalProperties).resourceBehaviorOptions` still returns `SubscriptionDisabled` and emails have to be picked up in `Groups` folder in Outlook not in `Inbox`